# Organize tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question about application programming using Python and tkinter.

All the simple examples I see in tutorials use one class for all the widgets and all the bound methods.  I decided to do this from the start since I saw no other examples, not thinking anything about it.  As my application has grown, I've got a lot of methods in this one class, and it's getting kind of ridiculous.

Luckily, I am designing a front end for an application that I had already made for the console, so the application logic itself is contained in another class, but I still have a lot of methods in my one front end class.

Is there some other way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can follow the MVC design pattern (Model-View-Controller):

- You keep your application logic in its class (Model).
- You separate your view to two parts: a Controller which contains event listeners and the View which contains the widgets.

I have done it this way for a Java application with Swing. From my modest experience with Python & Tkinter you can follow the MVC patters here to.

This link can inspire you [MVC example with Tkinter](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ToyMVC)